# PHP - Non-standard sorting of an Array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an Array that I need to sort, I will post an example for better understanding.
This is my unsorted Array:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [title] => This is some title
        [catid] => 1
    )    
[1] => Array
    (
        [title] => This is some title
        [catid] => 1
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [title] => This is some title
        [catid] => 2
    )    
[3] => Array
    (
        [title] => This is some title
        [catid] => 2
    )
```

I need to re-sort it like this:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [title] => This is some title
        [catid] => 1
    )    
[1] => Array
    (
        [title] => This is some title
        [catid] => 2
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [title] => This is some title
        [catid] => 1
    )    
[3] => Array
    (
        [title] => This is some title
        [catid] => 2
    )
```

I'll have more that two categories and I need to select one item per category so if I have 3 categories, my catid in that case will be sorted like this:

**catid:** 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3

Thanks

Comment: could it ever be 1,2,3,1,3?

Comment: more accurately, what happens if there's not an even lineup of 1,2,3's like 5 1's, 2 2's 1 3 or something

Comment: The general approach I'd take is to convert the array first to a 2-dimensional array: first dimension is `catid`, second dimension is all the associative arrays with that category. Then loop through each category, pulling an element off its sub-array and pushing it onto the result array.

Comment: @Arian - Yes, it *should be like that

Comment: @CrayonViolent In that case Array should be sorted like 1,2,3,1,2,1,1,1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my take:

```
/** just generating some data, not part of script **/
$originalArray = array();
$title = range('a','z');
for ($x=0;$x<20;$x++) {
  shuffle($title);
  $originalArray[] = array(
    'title' => implode(array_slice($title,0,rand(4,9))),
    'catid' => rand(1,3)
  );
}
/** end generating data **/


$tempArray = array();
foreach ($originalArray as $array) {
  $tempArray[$array['catid']][] = $array['title'];
}
ksort($tempArray);

$newArray = array();
while (count($tempArray)>0) {
  foreach ($tempArray as $mKey => &$mArray) {
    if (count($mArray)>0)
      $newArray[] = array('title'=>array_shift($mArray),'catid'=>$mKey);
  }
  $tempArray = array_filter($tempArray);
}
```

Comment: `+1` @crayonviolent Great Answer! Way more elegant than mine. lol

Answer (score 2):

This is what I came up for a 1-d array, but it should work for 2d as well.

```
$array = [1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1];

sort($array);

$newarray;


do{
    $max= max($array);
    for($a = 0; $a <= $max; $a++){
        foreach($array as $key => $value){
            if($value == $a){
                $newarray[] = $value;
                unset($array[$key]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}while(!empty($array));
```

This

```
1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1
```

would become:

```
1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2
```